# Distributed priority queue with efficient arbitrary deletes?

Tags: redis, queue, rabbitmq, priority-queue, eventqueue

I'm looking at using two Strict Fibonacci Queues—`queue_0` and `queue_1`—where `queue_0` holds the datetime ordered events (`key`) and `queue_1` holds the deletes.

Then I can simply run:

```
if(queue_0->findMin() == queue_1->findMin())
    queue_0->deleteMin(), queue_1->deleteMin;
```

That way at the expense of a non constant increase in auxiliary memory; inserts takes O(1), arbitrary "deletes" and delete-min's take O(lg n).
[all worst-case complexities; with cost of second queue being no more than 2× complexity of first queue in worst case; i.e.: equivalent in Big-Oh]

So, are there any open-source distributed priority queues with efficient arbitrary deletes? - E.g.: using this simple approach or one with better complexities? - Maybe integratable with Redis or similar?